# Macro from on open event for worksheet

Tags: vba

I have a `macro` that I want to run as part of open event.  I recorded the macro to copy and paste some columns on a worksheet.  This macro will only work when I am on that worksheet.

Since I want to run this macro as one of many applications when workbook is open and it doesn't always open on this specific worksheet I would like the code to target the worksheet and run the macro.

Here is **my code** but for some reason it **doesn't work :**

```
Application.Run "'Workbook.xlsb'!Sheet5.Copy_Paste2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, you need to call Copy_Paste2 from ThisWorkbook Open event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet5.Copy_Paste2
End Sub
```

Comment: That didn't work.  With the original code I get this message: Cannot run the macro "..." The macro may not be available in the workbook or all macros may be disabled.  I know macros are not disable because the others ones that are not worksheet specific run just fine.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe you can show us a bit more of the original code?